# electron cannot find module package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, electron

this is my first time using electron and im trying to run an express app, it gives me this error

Update code

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\package.json'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\marku_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you trying to run it from the folder of your application?

Comment: Yes offcourse, i dont know why this bug happened but i have fixed it by making a empty package.json at c/

Comment: that's a weird bug

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved your project from one dir to another? I got the same error when doing so and fixed it through the following steps:

1) Remove the node_modules dir;
`rm -rf node_modules`

2) Install the dependencies;
`npm install`

3) Build it again;
`npm run build:prod`